# how to use var as key of object into react project

Tags: reactjs, state

My state looks like :

```
 this.state = {
            service1 : { options: [
                {
                    id:1,
                    name:"AAAA",
                },
                {
                    id:2,
                    name:"BBB"
                },
                {
                    id:3,
                    name:"CCC"
                },
            ]},
            service2: {
                options : [
                    {
                        id:1,
                        name:'EEE'
                    },
                ]
            },
            formId:parseInt(this.props.match.params.formId),
            wsId:parseInt(this.props.match.params.wsId),
            service: this.props.match.params.service, // is string and equals service1 or service2
            ...
        }
```

in my render, I have this

```
<Option options={this.state.options} type={'actions'} />
```

How to telle to my Option component that i want this.state.service1.options or this.state.service2 for example ? knowing that service in my state = 'service1' or 'service2'.

I tested `this.state.${this.state.service}.options` but I have an error....

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can use the bracket notation `this.state[this.state.service].options`

Comment: I'm not sure how `{this.state.options}` would even work. You're leapfrogging a level of the object.

Comment: @dev_junwen thanks so much !!